# trying to shrink VARCHAR () FOR BIT DATA '(Binary data value not displayed)' to length 255

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, derby

I have a `Market` entity as

```
@Entity
public class Market extends MutableEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Embedded
    private Version marketVersion; // snipped
```

and `Version` entity as

```
@Embeddable
public class Version {
    private double versionNumber;
    private VersionType versionType;
    private DateTime publishedOn;
    private DateTime retiredOn;
    private double parentVersionNumber; //snipped
```

When I try to test the following, it fails

```
   @Test
    public void testCloneMarket() {
        final String name = "testCloneMarket";
        final String description = "testCloneMarket";
        final Market existingMarket = new MarketManager(crudService).addMarket(name, description);

        // publish market
        existingMarket.getMarketVersion().setPublishedOn(new DateTime()); // fails here


        assertNotNull(existingMarket);
    }
```

I see error as

```
testCloneMarket(com.myorg.project.versioning.business.MarketManagerTest)  Time elapsed: 4.11 sec  <<< ERROR!
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:90)
    at com.myorg.toolkit.commons.persistence_testing.rules.JpaRule.commitOrRollbackTransaction(JpaRule.java:220)
    at com.myorg.toolkit.commons.persistence_testing.rules.JpaRule.changeTransaction(JpaRule.java:155)
    at com.myorg.project.versioning.business.MarketManagerTest.testCloneMarket(MarketManagerTest.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR () FOR BIT DATA '(Binary data value not displayed)' to length 255.
```

I am using `derby` for in-memory tests. 
Why is this happening and what is the resolution for it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your ``.sql`` that you load in the database?

Comment: @Vakimshaar, where can I find that? I am new to this, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I can not find the source of `setPublishedOn`.

Only a Try !!

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
existingMarket.getMarketVersion().setPublishedOn(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear which column is experiencing the truncation error.

You can try to get more information from the exception chain by fully unwinding it: [see this advice](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain).

Or if you can find your derby.log file, and can run your application with -Dderby.language.logStatementText=true, you should be able to see more details.

The Derby datatype [VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefsqlj32714.html#rrefsqlj32714) supports a specified length up to 32,672 bytes. There is no default length, so the 256 byte length must be something that you have set in your application or in one of the frameworks that you are using to implement your persistence layer.

If you can figure out where your persistence layer is generating the table schema, you should be able to override it and choose a different length for the VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA column.